# Graphic Design Software Help SE Proposal

Tags: discussion

A member of the Graphic Design Stack Exchange has proposed a software support exchange specifically for graphic design software such as Photoshop and Lightroom among others. I haven't personally weighed in yet but wanted to bring it to you all for additional input.

Here is the Meta Discussion on GD.SE: [Creating a “Graphic Design Software Support” Stack](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2592/creating-a-graphic-design-software-support-stack)

And the actual proposal: [Graphic Design Software Support (Area 51 Proposal)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86994/graphic-design-software-support/)

Comment: I like this proposal. Hopefully my +1 will help get it some attention. I have no business in there (at least not yet), but I think it can help both communities.

Comment: Adobe Lightroom is *not* graphic design software.